# Syntax Error with Code Php

Tags: php

I keep getting this syntax error with this line of code.

```
$subject = 'Message - General Inquiry from '.$field_name' with the email of '.$field_email;
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$subject = 'Message - General Inquiry from '.$field_name.' with the email of '.$field_email;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `.` operator after `$field_name`. On the other hand, if you just use interpolation you don't have to bother with `.` operators:

```
$subject = "Message - General Inquiry from $field_name with the email of $field_email";
```